# How to pass parameters to Hadoop ToolRunner (or any MapReduce Action) from Oozie workflow

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, oozie

From the command line, parameters can be passed to ToolRunner as follows:

`hadoop jar myJar.jar com.Main -Dprop1=prop1value -Dprop2=prop2value`

I want to invoke my MapReduce job as part of a MapReduce action from Oozie.

I tried defining properties in the workflow as follows:

```
<property>
     <name>param1</name>
     <value>Hello World</value>
</property>
```

**EDIT**
This is how I'm trying to read the parameters from my MapReduce job:

```
Job job = new Job();
Configuration conf = job.getConfiguration();
System.out.println(conf.get("param1"));
```

But I'm unable to read it from the mapreduce program.

Although My question says passing parameters to ToolRunner, I don't think this is specific to toolrunner. It is general to a MapReduce job invoked using an Oozie MapReduce action.
Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try these examples?
here http://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.3.2/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a3.2.2_Map-Reduce_Action
and here http://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.3.2/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a4_Parameterization_of_Workflows

Comment: Yes, I've gone through these already. These examples tell you how to run a general MapReduce action & how to configure the MapReduce job (map class, reduce class, etc..) but they don't cover how to pass parameters to the job

Comment: can you provide an example how do you pass and try to get parameters?

Comment: added to my question, I'm passing the parameters by defining the property as said in my question within the `<configuration>` tag in workflow.xml